# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.SearchView

Tags: android

Estoy usando el componente **SearchView** en una aplicación, al parecer en algunos dispositivos está ocasionando crashes.

¿Cual creen que pueda ser el problema y como podría solucionarlo?

Este es el **SearchView** que tengo en mi XML:

```
  <SearchView
      android:id="@+id/searchProduct"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:searchIcon="@null"
      android:closeIcon="@null"
    />
```

Mi gradle:

```
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
```

Esta es la activity ***SearchPromotionsActivity:*** El layout de está Activity contiene un toolbar que en realidad es un XML que lo añado al layout del "SearchPromotionsActivity", dentro de este se encuentra el searchView, un imageView con una lupita que abre el searchView, un textView que es el título y un imageView con botón atrás, y por último un RecyclerView.

```
SearchView searchView;
private boolean pressed = false;
private ImageView imgSearch;
private InputMethodManager imm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_promotions);

    searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchProduct);
    imgSearch = findViewById(R.id.imgSearch);

    imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    findViewById(R.id.svOpenSearchView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Lo que hace esto es ocultar un imageView que contiene
            //una imagen de una lupa y muestra el searchView
            //también muestra y oculta el teclado                  
            if(!pressed){
                findViewById(R.id.searchProduct).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.txtSearchPromotions).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgSearch.setImageResource(R.drawable.closeblue);
                searchView.requestFocus();
                if(imm!=null){
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
                }
                pressed = true;
            }else{
                findViewById(R.id.searchProduct).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.txtSearchPromotions).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgSearch.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);
                findViewById(R.id.ly).requestFocus();
                if(imm!=null){
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                pressed = false;
            }
        }
    });


    //Acción del searchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (query != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchPromotionsActivity.this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("query", query);
                if(imm!=null) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Este es log:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pe.beyond.movistar.prioritymoments/pe.beyond.movistar.prioritymoments.activities.startSection.SearchPromotionsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.SearchView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.SearchView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at pe.beyond.movistar.prioritymoments.activities.startSection.SearchPromotionsActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at pe.beyond.movistar.prioritymoments.activities.startSection.SearchPromotionsActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(int[])' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.SearchView.updateCloseButton(SearchView.java:852)
       at android.widget.SearchView.updateViewsVisibility(SearchView.java:801)
       at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:367)
       at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:258)
       at android.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:916)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(Unknown Source)
       at pe.beyond.movistar.prioritymoments.activities.startSection.SearchPromotionsActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Comment: el problema es en la actividad donde lo estas llamando

Comment: Pon el código de tu : SearchPromotionsActivity

Comment: @diegoveloper, lo acabo de actualizar, a ver si lo puedes revisar, porque yo la verdad no encuentro el error.

Comment: que contiene este archivo: activity_search_promotions

Comment: Contiene un toolbar que en realidad es un XML que lo añado al layout del "SearchPromotionsActivity", dentro de este se encuentra el searchView, un imageView con una lupita que abre el **searchView**, un textView que es el título y un imageView con botón atrás, y por último un RecyclerView.

Comment: puedes ponerlo en tu pregunta

Comment: @diegoveloper Listo, lo acabo de editar.

Answer (score 0):

Según el error que se muestra en el Log :

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(int[])' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.SearchView.updateCloseButton(SearchView.java:852)
```

No puedes ponerle nulo desde XML, si quieres ocultarlo intenta desde código con el

```
mSearchView.setIconified(false);
```

**Ocultar el Close Button**

Usando estilos :

> Para versiones menores de 21:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/AppTheme.WidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.WidgetTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

> Para versiones 21 arriba:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Justo buscando en Internet encontré algo sobre ese error, lo que hice fue actualizar dos valores: *searchIcon* y *closeIcon* y cambiar el **null** a **android:color/transparent**  en el xml, eso lo solucionaría o tengo que poner lo que tú me recomiendas en el activity?

Comment: aún mejor lo puedes hacer usando estilos , ya actualicé mi respuesta, eso debe ir dentro del styles.xml de acuerdo a la versión

Comment: Entiendo, lo probaré; pero eso sería entonces lo que estaría ocasionando los crashes cierto? o algo más también, tomando en cuenta lo que muestra el log.

Comment: Solo sería eso, intentalo y me avisas.

Comment: Tengo que esperar que esta actualización salga a producción todavía, pero no te preocupes que si funciona daré como valida tu respuesta.